# Qt tableWidget column reference by name or alias

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I am new to Qt and have only a little C++ experience and am developing a desktop app.

I am using the tableWidget and my code populates the cells by (row, column) pointers. This is OK at the moment but I can see that if I need to add or move a column that I will have a jolly time fixing all the pointers sprinkled through my code.

Is there a way to use an alias for a column number and reference the cells by this alias? e.g., instead of

```
ui->tableWidget1->setItem(0, 3, new QTableWidgetItem(ui->lblWeight->text()));
```

could I have something more like

```
ui->tableWidget1->setItem(0, "colWeight", new QTableWidgetItem(ui->lblWeight->text()));
```

where "colWeight" has been assigned to column 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the aliases don't change during run-time, I would use an *enum* instead of a variable.

```
enum Column
{
    ColumnA = 0,
    ColumnB = 1,
    ColumnC = 2
};

ui->tableWidget1->setItem(0, ColumnA, new QTableWidgetItem(ui->lblWeight->text()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `colWeight` as a variable:

```
int colWeight = 3; // Your column indicator
...
ui->tableWidget1->setItem(0, colWeight, new QTableWidgetItem(ui->lblWeight->text()));
```

Comment: That's a good low-tech solution, thanks! How do I make the variables global in scope. I was looking that up and didn't quite understand it.

Comment: if you are not going to have more than one instance of yourtable widget, declaring a variable `static` gives you easier access. Just be careful with the naming and keep track of how and when do you modify the variables.